# Fastest way to save image stream on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, compression

We have a camera connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 via USB3. The camera can only provide RAW images [2056x1542x3] which we can read at about 30 FPS. On the Raspberry Pi 4 we need to save these images to disk - due to space and write speed to the SD card it is not feasible to save the RAW images (10 MB/piece) at any rate really. Instead we want to compress these images and then save them as fast as possible.

Our current solution looks similar to the below snippet:

```python
def save_image(frame,filename):
    cv2.imwrite(filename,frame)

...

(ret, frame) = cam.get_next_frame()
if ret == IS_SUCCESS:
    timestamp = get_timestamp()
    filename = conf["cv_image_folder"] + timestamp + ".jpg"
    save_thread = threading.Thread(target=save_image, args=(frame,filename,))
    save_thread.start()
```

OpenCV is compiled with `libjpeg-turbo` and all possible HW-flags for accelerated computing. At about 5 or 6 FPS the Raspberry Pi 4 uses about 100% of all 4 cores. The same goes for a non-threaded configuration. We manually set the framerate on the camera and monitor the number of threads spawned (which is about 3-4 concurrent threads at 5-6 FPS). We choose JPEG (even though its lossy) since PNG or TIFF compression takes longer to compute.

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the quality on the `cv2.imwrite()`?

Comment: I haven't - the default value is 95 on JPEGs and we want to maintain as good a quality as possible, so this seemed as a good value. I know that quality is debatable when using JPEGs in the first place, but since this seems as our only option we need to make the best of it.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a fast USB3 second disk in one of the USB slots and alternate files between the two disks?

Comment: Write speeds are not the current issue. Monitoring the CPU load shows that they max out completely at 5-6 FPS on then the camera will start to drop images (or lag).

Comment: I would definitely try around 80% quality and see how you go.

Comment: You could also try leaving 4 threads running and waiting on a condition variable or message rather than starting the thread afresh each time. Then send the frames round-robin to the different threads. There is the new shared memory in Python 3.6 which means that you don't have to send the data to each thread but instead can share the memory holding the frame.

Comment: Also, can you get the camera to deliver your JPEGs with `cam.get_next_frame()` instead of Numpy arrays? That will hopefully do the JPEG compression on the video core rather than the CPU. Which library is that from - you have removed the `import` statements...

Comment: Didn't knew about the shared memory - will look into that. But again, I think the real issue is powering through the image encodings.
Unfortunately, the camera does not offer any onboard compression. It is a typical machine vision camera from IDS-imaging using the ```ueye``` SDK.

Comment: Just testing saving a "dummy" image on my laptop with lower quality. There is little to no change in the CPU load. But it could be different on a Pi. To be tested at least.

Comment: @Jesper have you tried resizing the image smaller? This way the saved image will be much smaller and when you need to "use" the image, you can enlarge it again

Comment: That would greatly reduce the quality of the image. Which we really don’t want to do.

Comment: I just did some experiments with `blosc`. I don't have the same setup as you, but I found that it can compress an image from the Raspberry Pi camera of the same size as yours to around 60% of its full size remarkably fast. Maybe worth a try. I just did `PACKED = blosc.pack_array(NUMPY_IMAGE)` Details here http://python-blosc.blosc.org/tutorial.html

Comment: Those are rather large images. Trying worst case (random data) with regular jpeg at 95%, i get about 12 FPS on an i7-4930k. You're running at around 40% clock frequency, with less efficient instruction set, smaller cache, significantly smaller memory bandwidth... can't imagine you can squish out much more out of that machine unless you loosen some restriction somewhere. First, you're CPU bound, so drop the compression (or use some lighter image codec as Mark suggests, or run the raw pixel data through some quick generic compressor.... or go raw.

Comment: I would also check whether you can get a Bayer image from the camera instead of the already demosaiced RGB one. That would cut the amount of data to 1/3. And then some light lossless compression (if you're gonna do some processing on it, avoid any unnecessary loss of quality), and dump it on bit, fast storage.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, will make sure to check that out tomorrow.

Comment: @DanMašek we can get Bayer from the camera. But have no experience in getting the colors in post. Is that something OpenCV can do? Light lossless compression - would that be TIFF or PNG or do you know of any lighter? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `cvtColor` can do the demosaicing. You definitely need to store it losslessly in that case -- something like JPEG would make a mess of the colours. In my projects, I do archive the bayer images (since that's what the sensor produces), but since I wanted to reuse my pre-existing archive format, I just use a generic compressor to compress the raw pixels (along with some relevant metadata). | Lighter than low compression level zlib... maybe something like lz4 or snappy.

Comment: Try to max out your storage bandwidth (a USB flash drive will probably be better than the SD card). Even raw Bayer at that size, 30 FPS, that's about 95 MB/s or some ~45 minutes worth on a 256 GB drive which can be had for some 50 USD? See how that runs, and if you've got CPU to spare, you can trade of some CPU usage for potential reduction in needed storage. Don't box yourself in with too many strict requirements. Spending a bit more on hardware (assuming this is a one-off project) is worth avoiding the days of tearing your hair out (which might be futile at end).

Comment: Bayer should be a great way to go - well suggested Dan! Please update us with how you get on @Jesper.

Comment: I tested with Bayer images. Before the de-bayering processing load was put on the Raspberry Pi by the camera API which for 10 FPS took about 150% CPU. With no real-time de-bayering, i.e. just receiving bayer images this is about 10% CPU. Great reduction in load! File size with bayer images is a 3rd of what RAW RGB is. Current limitation is now write speed to the SD card which caps out at about 12-13 FPS ~ 50-55 MB/s. Fix: USB3 drive - to be tested. For compression I could only get about 10% from ```blosc```, which is not worth the added CPU load. It would be good with smaller files though.

Answer (score 5):

I think Dan's discovery that you can get the Bayer image is going to prove the solution to your problem, however I did some work on the concept of using Broadcom's MMAL *"Mulitmedia Abstraction Layer"* to do JPEG encoding on the VideoCore GPU to lessen the CPU load and wanted to place it here. It may prove useful to you in combination with Dan's suggestion and/or to other folk seeking to do similar things.

As a result of running on the GPU, it can encode your (rather large) images to disk at around 4 frames per second **whilst using almost no CPU**. I observed 3 CPU cores were idle and the fourth core hovered on and off around 10-15% usage.

The code just takes a single image called `"image.jpg"` and resizes it to the dimensions you are using and then repeatedly encodes that and sends it to disk 100 times.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io
import numpy as np
from picamera import mmal, mmalobj as mo
from PIL import Image
from threading import Event

# Globals
w, h = 2048, 1536      # These seem to need to be multiples of 64, or maybe 16
EncoderAvail = Event()
EncoderAvail.set()

# Set up MMAL-based JPEG encoding
encoder = mo.MMALImageEncoder()
encoder.inputs
encoder.inputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_RGB24
encoder.inputs[0].framesize = (w, h)
encoder.inputs[0].commit()
encoder.outputs[0].copy_from(encoder.inputs[0])
encoder.outputs[0].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_JPEG
encoder.outputs[0].commit()
encoder.outputs[0].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_JPEG_Q_FACTOR] = 90

def image_callback(port, buf):
    with open(f"frame-{frame}.jpg", 'wb') as jpeg:
        jpeg.write(buf.data)
        EncoderAvail.set()
    #return bool(buf.flags & mmal.MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_FLAG_FRAME_END)
    return True

encoder.outputs[0].enable(image_callback)
encoder.inputs[0].enable(lambda port, buf: True)

# Encode the same image repeatedly as we are measuring the encode time not acquire time
im = Image.open('image.jpg').resize((w,h))
rgb_data = np.array(im)

for frame in range(100):
    print(f"Frame: {frame}")

    # Make red bar across top that gets longer with each frame to be sure we are getting them all
    rgb_data[0:10,:frame,0] = 255

    EncoderAvail.wait()
    buf = encoder.inputs[0].get_buffer()
    buf.data = rgb_data[:]
    EncoderAvail.clear()
    encoder.inputs[0].send_buffer(buf)

encoder.outputs[0].disable()
encoder.inputs[0].disable()
```

The code is heavily based on the Picamera MMAL stuff - [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_mmalobj.html). The code is probably not optimal - for example, I do not know how to increase the number of buffers to 2 which would enable double-buffering and potentially make a big difference. I am also not sure how to make it more event-driven as it is rather synchronous at the moment.

As I said, you can change it to encode Bayer images to JPEG, by changing `mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_RGB24` so you may be able to still use it.

If anyone knows more about the MMAL stuff and is able to improve it, please feel free to take my code, improve it and add it as a new answer and let me know so we can all learn.

I noticed that it doesn't currently seem to honour the JPEG Quality setting either, so if anyone can improve that, please let me know.

**Keywords**: Raspberry Pi, GPU, JPEG encoding, JPEG encoder, MMAL, Videocore GPU, Broadcom, Multimedia Abstraction Layer, Raspi.